# Fade in from side of screen

Tags: c#, animation, slide

I am trying to make a simple sidebar which will slide in and out from the left side of the desktop. This is my code at the moment, but it doesn't actually work, and I fear it may be inefficient.

```
    private void fadeIn()
    {
        if (this.Width == 1)
            while (this.Size.Width < 36)
            {
                this.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width + 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - this.Width);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
                this.Invalidate();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
    }

    private void fadeOut()
    {
        if (this.Width == 36)
            while (this.Size.Width > 1)
            {
                this.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width - 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - this.Width);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
                this.Invalidate();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
    }
```

Hopefuly someone may be able to help me with this. It should be fairly simple.

Comment: That's a terrible way of doing it. Try doing it in a timer. You should never block the ui thread like that (or use DoEvents for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question about zooming form with fading, if yes you can use this class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace formAnimation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Win32 implementation to show / hide a window with animation.
    /// </summary>

    public class WinAPI
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Animates the window from left to right. This flag can be used with roll or slide animation.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0X1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Animates the window from right to left. This flag can be used with roll or slide animation.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0X2;
        /// <summary>
        /// Animates the window from top to bottom. This flag can be used with roll or slide animation.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_VER_POSITIVE = 0X4;
        /// <summary>
        /// Animates the window from bottom to top. This flag can be used with roll or slide animation.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_VER_NEGATIVE = 0X8;
        /// <summary>
        /// Makes the window appear to collapse inward if AW_HIDE is used or expand outward if the AW_HIDE is not used.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_CENTER = 0X10;
        /// <summary>
        /// Hides the window. By default, the window is shown.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_HIDE = 0X10000;
        /// <summary>
        /// Activates the window.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_ACTIVATE = 0X20000;
        /// <summary>
        /// Uses slide animation. By default, roll animation is used.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_SLIDE = 0X40000; 
        /// <summary>
        /// Uses a fade effect. This flag can be used only if hwnd is a top-level window.
        /// </summary>
        public const int AW_BLEND = 0X80000;

        /// <summary>
        /// Animates a window.
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        public static  extern int AnimateWindow (IntPtr hwand , int dwTime , int dwFlags) ;     
    } 
}
```

And then you can write little code to animate the form like this:

```
WinAPI.AnimateWindow (this.Handle, animationTime, flags);
```

If you like to see simple demo of using this code download this open source code from [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?u6h2leluwkjfmqf)